# Show that $\max\{|S|,|T|\}\leq|S\cup T|\leq|S|+|T|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I want to show that $\max\{|S|,|T|\}\leq|S\cup T|\leq|S|+|T|$ for any denumerable (or countably infinite) sets $S$ and $T$.

Background:

In the process of showing that $S$ and $T$ being denumerable implies that $S\cup T$ is denumerable, I realized there are two cases to consider:

1. $S$ and $T$ are disjoint, and
2. $S$ and $T$ are not disjoint

I say that w.l.o.g. we can assume that $S\cap T=\emptyset,$ because if the sets aren’t disjoint, then $|S\cup T|<|S|+|T|$. But at most, the cardinality of $S\cup T$ is $|S|+|T|$; so showing that $$h(n):= \begin{cases} 
      f\left(\frac{n}{2}\right) & n\in E \\
      h\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right) & n\in O \\ 
   \end{cases} $$
is a bijection from $\mathbb{N}\to S\cup T$ where $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions such that $f:\mathbb{N}\to S$ and $g:\mathbb{N}\to T$ shows that $S\cup T$ is denumerable in the case when the intersection is empty. Is it true that there is no loss of generality assuming that $S$ and $T$ are disjoint? My reasoning is that it is enough to show that $S\cup T $ is denumerable when the two sets are disjoint since this shows that $$|\text{denumerable set}|<|S\cup T|\leq|S|+|T|$$

I would like to be thorough and prove that $\max\{|S|,|T|\}|\leq|S\cup T|\leq|S|+|T|$ in my proof of $S\cup T$ being denumerable. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to break into cases, and this is even true without any assumptions on denumerability.

- To show that $|S|\le |S\cup T|$, you just need to find an injection from $S$ to $S\cup T$.
- To show that $\max(|S|,|T|)\le |S\cup T|$, you need to show $|S|\le |S\cup T|$ and $|T|\le |S\cup T|$.

The hard part is showing $|S\cup T|\le |S|+|T|$. One way to do this is to find an injection from $S\cup T$ to $(S\times \{1\})\cup (T\times \{2\})$, as the latter two sets are disjoint and have sizes $|S|$ and $|T|$. One such injection is
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
(x,1) & x\in S\\
(x,2) & x\notin S
\end{cases}
$$
**Edit** Perhaps more simply, since $S\cup T$ is the disjoint union of $S$ and $T\setminus S$, you have
$$
|S\cup T|=|S|+|T\setminus S|\le |S|+|T|,
$$
where the last inequality follows since $T\setminus S$ is a subset of $T$, so its size is at most that of $T$ (in general, if $A\subset B$, then the inclusion map $A\to B$ is an injection, proving $|A|\le |B|$).